# Typescript: How do I use two colors depending on type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am defining a color prop depending on the type of display.

```
colorStyle: {
                textAlign: "center",
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                color: (theme.colors.BaseColor.Red as any).Red4,
            }
```

This is the current code which gives a text for all the notification types with the color red. I am trying to update it to show red color only if it is an error and black to all other notifications.

**Is there a way that I can change it in the same prop or do I need to create a new prop and pull that into the api and display it there writing a conditional statement?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to update it to show red color only if it is an error and black to all other notifications.

Create *two* styles. One with the normal color and one with red. Only apply the one with the red *when* there is an error.

You would put this conditional logic in the react render of your component / page etc.